# Dynamic jQuery asp.net mvc messy code, how to refactor more cleanly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a very interactive site with lots of ajax type functions.

I'm starting to end up with a fair amount of message Jquery code, all nestled in together with my bee sting tags.

For example

```
<% foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.goalId))
{ %>
//$('#AddNew2<%= Html.Encode(group.Key) %>').html('<input type="text" name="" value=""/>');
$('#AddNew2<%= Html.Encode(group.Key) %>').one('click', function(event) {
    $('#AddNew2<%= Html.Encode(group.Key) %>').html('<input id="AddNew2<%= Html.Encode(group.Key) %>" type="text" name="" value=""/>').focus();

        $('#AddNew2<%= Html.Encode(group.Key) %>').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        //Do something
        alert("hello");
        }
        //This will display the keycode
        //alert(code);
        //            
        });   
});
```

My Question is two fold

1. Rather than having all of this code inside a view, or the Master site template, can I refactor this else where, perhaps using a .ascx control? Or can I just import a .js file and still have <% %> tags work inside it?
2. Am I using jQuery in a very bad way? It feels that I am being too simplistic with my use of the selectors, as I feel there would be a much cleaner way to select the elements I need.

Please bare in mind that I will have many different lists of data that can all be added to/updated on the same page, potentially up to hundreds of different elements and id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could (and arguably should) use a javascript variable to hold the value and simply re-use it.  That will improve the readability of your code.  Second, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do -- it looks like you are setting up a click handler on each element.  I'd suggest that you give them all a class and then use the class as the selector for applying the element.  Third, it appears that you are creating a new element with the same id as an existing element.  That would be a no-no.  You should give it a new id and/or name.  You may not need the id on the exterior element if you use a class.

Ex.

Layout:

```
<% foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.goalId)) { %>
   <p>
     <input type="button" value="Add" class="add-goal" />
     <input type="hidden" value='<%= group.Key %>' />
   </p>
<% } %>
```

Script

```
$('.add-goal').one( 'click', function() {
    var goalid = $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').attr('value');
    var parent = $(this).parent().html('');
    $( '<input type="text" id="AddNew2' + goalid
           + '" name="AddNew2' + goalid + '" value="" />' )
        .appendTo(parent)
        .keypress( function(e) {
            ...
        });

});
```